# How to open a link without knowing its URL in new tab using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I wanted to click a link in facebook group post which has href attribute as "#" but when we click on it that href attribute will automatically change to particular URL so I just wanted to click on link so that it will open in new tab.

Sorry I don't have any code to explain this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't provide nor code nor a link to that page I answered it with some example code on how to open a link in a new tab:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
actions = ActionChains(driver)
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/")
link = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='s-navigation--item js-gps-track']")))
actions.key_down(Keys.CONTROL)
actions.click(on_element=link)
actions.perform()
```

Anyway this is it: you use ActionChains to control+click (open in new tab) the link. With that you can perform every complex operation. A list of available actions/methods can be found [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/action-chains-in-selenium-python/).

EDIT: Ah, if then (I guess) you want to move from a tab to another you can easily do it like this:

```
tabs = driver.window_handles
driver.switch_to.window(tabs[1])
```

Where `tabs` is a zero-based list (tabs[0] is the first tab, tabs[1] the second and so on...)

Comment: I am able to click on the link but what I want is to open that link in new tab and as I mention I don't have href attribute so how this thing should be achieved?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the page? .-.

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/groups/1300275210137759 this is the link where I am clicking on date time area and wanted to open that link in new tab after clicking

Comment: Oh, I just edited the answer lol

Comment: I edited the answer to add an explanation on how to swap from a tab focus to another, check it out ;)